# Atom editor end of line shortcut (without end button)

Tags: atom-editor, shortcut

In my laptop keyboard I can move cursor to end of line by pressing FN + right arrow buttons.
Now I am coding on a desktop and this keyboard doesn't have that combination.
I can move cursor to end of line by pressing "END" button but I don't want to use END button I just want to add this functionality to a similar combination what I had in my other keyboard.
So I am looking a way to create shotcut to press ALT + Right Arrow to make same functionality as END button. Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all documentation and making some tries I found out how to move cursor end of the line.

First go to `File -> Keymap` this will open `keymap.cson` file on here just add codes under `'atom-text-editor'`. It will look like as below.

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'alt-right': 'editor:move-to-end-of-line'
    'alt-left': 'editor:move-to-beginning-of-line'
```

So now you can move your cursor end of line by pressing `ALT + Right` or visa versa.